# KeyListener/KeyEvent not working?

Tags: java, event-handling, keylistener

My Key Listener/Event isn't triggering at all. Is there something I'm missing here or maybe somewhere else?

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import java.awt.Rectangle;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Player implements KeyListener{

    private final double speed = 5.0d;

    private BufferedImage pSprite;
    private Rectangle rect;
    private double xPos, yPos;
    private int width, height;
    private boolean right = false, left = false;

    //=============================================================================

    public Player(double xPos, double yPos, int width, int height){
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        rect = new Rectangle((int)xPos, (int)yPos, width, height);


        try{
            URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/images/Player.png");
            pSprite = ImageIO.read(url);
        }catch(IOException e){};
    }// Player

    public void draw(Graphics2D g){
        g.drawImage(pSprite, (int)xPos, (int)yPos, width, height, null);

    }// draw

    //=============================================================================

    public void update(double delta){
        if(right && !left){
            xPos += speed * delta;
            rect.x = (int) xPos;


        }
        else if(!right && left ){
            xPos -= speed * delta;
            rect.x = (int) xPos;
        }// if

    }// update

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D||key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            right = true;
            System.out.println("right");
        }// if

        else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A || key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            left = true;
            System.out.println("left");

        }// else if

    }// keyPressed

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D||key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            right = false;
        }

        else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A || key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            left = false;
        }


    }// keyReleased

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }// keyTyped

}
```

```
package game_screen;

import java.awt.Canvas;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import state.SuperStateMachine;

public class GameScreen implements SuperStateMachine{

    private Player player;

    public GameScreen(){
        player = new Player(150, 150, 50, 50);
    }// GameScreen

    @Override
    public void update(double delta) {
        player.update(delta);
    }// update

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        player.draw(g);
    }// draw

    @Override
    public void init(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.addKeyListener(player);
    }

}// class GameScreen
```

package display;

import java.awt.Canvas;

import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import state.StateMachine;

public class Display extends Canvas implements Runnable{

```
public static int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Thread thread;
private boolean running = false;
public int FPS;


public static void main(String[] args){

    // Display Window/Frame
    Display display = new Display();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(display);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setTitle("Space Invaders");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    display.start();
}// main

public synchronized void start(){
    if(running)
        return;

    running = true;

    thread  = new Thread (this);
    thread.start();
}// Start

public synchronized void stop(){
    if(!running)
        return;

    running = false;

    try {
        thread.join();
    }// try 

    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }// catch
}// Stop

public static StateMachine state;

public Display(){
    this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    this.setFocusable(true);

    state = new StateMachine(this);
    state.setState((byte) 0);
}// Display Dimensions


@Override
public void run() {
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long lastLoopTime = System.nanoTime();
    final int TARGET_FPS = 60;
    final long OPTIMAL_TIME = 1000000000 / TARGET_FPS;
    int frames = 0;

    this.createBufferStrategy(3);
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();

    while(running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        long updateLength = now - lastLoopTime;
        lastLoopTime = now;
        double delta = updateLength / ((double)OPTIMAL_TIME);

        frames++;

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
            timer += 1000;
            FPS = frames;
            frames = 0;
            System.out.println(FPS);
        }// if

        draw(bs);
        update(delta);

        try{
            Thread.sleep(((lastLoopTime - System.nanoTime()) + OPTIMAL_TIME) / 1000000);
        }// try
        catch(Exception e){

        }// catch
    }// while
}// run

public void draw(BufferStrategy bs){
    do{
        do{ 
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH + 50, HEIGHT + 50);

            state.draw(g);

            g.dispose();
        }// do
            while(bs.contentsRestored());
            bs.show();
    }// do
        while(bs.contentsLost());
}// draw

public void update(double delta){
    state.update(delta);
}
```

}// Runnable

package sprite;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import timer.Timer;

public class SpriteAnimation {

```
private ArrayList<BufferedImage> sprites = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
private byte currentSprite;

private boolean loop = false;
private boolean play = false;
private boolean destroyAfterAnim = false;

private Timer timer;
private int animationSpeed;
private double xPos, yPos;

public SpriteAnimation(double xPos, double yPos, int animationSpeed){
    this.animationSpeed = animationSpeed;
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;

    timer = new Timer();
}// SpriteAnimation

public void draw(Graphics2D g){
    if(isSpriteAnimDestroyed())
        return;

    g.drawImage(sprites.get(currentSprite), (int)getxPos(), (int)getyPos(), null);
}// draw

public void update(double delta){
    if(isSpriteAnimDestroyed())
        return;

    if(loop && !play)
        loopAnimation();
    if(play && !loop)
        playAnimation();

}// update

public void stopAnimation(){
    loop = false;
    play = false;
}

public void resetSprite(){
    loop = false;
    play = false;
    currentSprite = 0;
}

private void loopAnimation(){
    if(timer.isTimerReady(animationSpeed) && currentSprite == sprites.size()-1){
        currentSprite = 0;
        timer.resetTimer();
    }// if

        else if(timer.timerEvent(animationSpeed) && currentSprite != sprites.size()-1){
        currentSprite++;
    }// else if

}// loopAnimation

private void playAnimation(){
    if(timer.timerEvent(animationSpeed) && currentSprite != sprites.size()-1 && !isDestroyAfterAnim()){
        play = false;
        currentSprite = 0;
    }// if

    else if(timer.timerEvent(animationSpeed) && currentSprite == sprites.size()-1 && isDestroyAfterAnim()){
        sprites = null;
    }// else if

    else if(timer.timerEvent(animationSpeed) && currentSprite != sprites.size()-1){
        currentSprite++;
    }// if
}// playAnimation



public byte getCurrentSprite() {
    return currentSprite;
}// getCurrentSprite

public void setCurrentSprite(byte currentSprite) {
    this.currentSprite = currentSprite;
}// setCurrentSprite


public boolean isLoop() {
    return loop;
}// isLoop

public void setLoop(boolean loop) {
    this.loop = loop;
}// setLoop


public boolean isSpriteAnimDestroyed(){
    if(sprites == null)
        return true;

    return false;
}// isSpriteAnimDestroyed

public void addSprite(BufferedImage spriteMap, int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height){
    sprites.add(spriteMap.getSubimage(xPos, yPos, width, height));
}// addSprite

public void PlayerAnimation(boolean play, boolean destroyAfterAnim){

    this.play = play;
    this.setDestroyAfterAnim(destroyAfterAnim);
}// PlayerAnimation

public double getxPos() {
    return xPos;
}// getxPos

public void setxPos(double xPos) {
    this.xPos = xPos;
}// setxPos


public double getyPos() {
    return yPos;
}// getyPos

public void setyPos(double yPos) {
    this.yPos = yPos;
}// setyPos

public boolean isDestroyAfterAnim() {
    return destroyAfterAnim;

}// isDestroyAfterAnim

public void setDestroyAfterAnim(boolean destroyAfterAnim) {
    this.destroyAfterAnim = destroyAfterAnim;

}// setDestroyAfterAnim
```

}// SpriteAnimation

package state;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import game_screen.GameScreen;

public class StateMachine {

```
private ArrayList<SuperStateMachine> states = new ArrayList<SuperStateMachine>();
private Canvas canvas;
private byte selectState = 0;

public StateMachine(Canvas canvas){
    SuperStateMachine game = new GameScreen();
    states.add(game);

    this.canvas = canvas;
}// StateMachine

public void draw(Graphics2D g){
    states.get(selectState).draw(g);
}// draw

public void update(double delta){
    states.get(selectState).update(delta);
}// update

public void setState(byte i){
    for(int r = 0; r < canvas.getKeyListeners().length; r++){
        canvas.removeKeyListener(canvas.getKeyListeners()[r]);
        selectState = i;
        states.get(selectState).init(canvas);
    }// for 
}// setState

public byte getStates(){
    return selectState;

}
```

}// StateMachine Class

package state;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public interface SuperStateMachine {

```
public void update(double delta);
public void draw(Graphics2D g);
public void init(Canvas canvas);
```

}

package timer;

public class Timer {

```
private long prevTime;

public Timer(){
    setPrevTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
}// timer

public long getPrevTime() {
    return prevTime;
}// getCurrentTime

public void setPrevTime(long currentTime) {
    this.prevTime = currentTime;
}// setCurrentTime

public void resetTimer(){
    prevTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public boolean timerEvent(int timer){
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - getPrevTime() > timer){
        resetTimer();
        return true;
    }// timerEvent

    return false;
}// timerEvent

public boolean isTimerReady(int timer){

    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - getPrevTime() > timer){
        return true;
    }   
    return false;
}
```

}// class Timer

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in your code above do I see `something.addKeyListener(...)`. A listener of any type will not work unless you add it to the listened to object. Having said that, most Swing work should avoid use of KeyListeners and instead favor Key Bindings, or if dealing with text components, then DocumentListener or DocumentFilter.

Other issues: your code snippet shows no GUI classes such as your JPanels, JFrame, etc... and so it will be hard to know what the rest of your code is doing, or if you add your KeyListener elsewhere, or if you do, if that component has the necessary focus.

What happens if you add a line here:

```
public Display() {
    this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    this.setFocusable(true);

    this.requestFocusInWindow(true);  // ***** add this line here ***

    state = new StateMachine(this);
    state.setState((byte) 0);
}
```

Note that I would avoid drawing on Canvas objects, I would avoid using all AWT components, and instead draw within the paintComponent method of a JPanel.

Comment: @Bashamock: What is the `SuperStateMachine` class that your class extends? This appears to be an AWT program and not a Swing program. I see that you are adding your KeyListener to a Canvas object, and I don't see that this object has been assigned system focus.

Comment: @Bashamock: then you're using a library or jar file that I'm not familiar with, one that contains the `SuperStateMachine` code. I'm not familiar with this class.

Comment: I've added the line of code and nothing seems to have changed